# Relation does not exist in adonis/node.js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have two tables: **book** and **book_units** as you can see below:

```
class BookSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('books', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('code').notNullable().unique()
      table.string('description')
      table.string('authors')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
}


class BookUnitSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('book_unit', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('book_id').references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
      table.integer('unit').notNullable().unique()
      table.integer('sequence').unique()
      table.string('description')
      table.integer('qt_question')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
}
```

In the **Book** model, i defined a relationship with book_units:

```
class Book extends Model {

    book_units () {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnit')
    }

}
```

And in the **Book Unit** Model:

```
class BookUnit extends Model {

    book () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Book')
    }

}
```

I'm trying to make a insert using postman in the **book_unit** using this json:

```
{
    "book_id": 1,
    "unit": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false
}
```

But i'm receiving:

> insert into "book_units" ("book_id", "created_at", "description",
>   "qt_question", "sequence", "status", "unit", "updated_at", "user_id")
>   values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) returning "id" - relation
>   "book_units" does not exist

This book with id 1 exist in database. Why i'm receiving this error?

Comment: please put detail error

Comment: you can try to changes your ```book_id``` to ```books_id```

Comment: the only detail error that i have is what i put on the question

Comment: change book_id to books_id where?

Comment: same error: insert into "book_units" ("books_id", "created_at", "description", "qt_question", "sequence", "status", "unit", "updated_at", "user_id") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) returning "id" - relation "book_units" does not exist

Comment: The error was `relation "book_units" does not exist`, but your schema had a line like this: `this.create('book_unit' `, and there is an extra 's' listed in the error. I'm not familiar with Postman, but is it possible the API endpoint contains an extra 's' when it should not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code.

I noticed this problem:

By default the `AdonisJS CLI` creates a table with the name : `book_units` (you code : `book_unit`) command: `> adonis make:migration BookUnit`

I solved the problem with (`App/Models/BookUnit`):

```js
class BookUnit extends Model {
    static get table() {
        return 'book_unit'
    } // Model table name

    ...
```

#### OR

change

```js
this.create('book_unit', (table) => {
```

by

```js
this.create('book_units', (table) => {
```

#### Explanation

Models and migrations are not linked. If you change the name of the table in the migration, it's necessary to pass it on to the model.

## Full code

schemas :

```js
class BookUnitSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.create('book_unit', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('book_id').references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
      table.integer('unit').notNullable().unique()
      table.integer('sequence').unique()
      table.string('description')
      table.integer('qt_question')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down() {
    this.drop('book_units')
  }
}

//=====================================

class BookSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.create('books', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('code').notNullable().unique()
      table.string('description')
      table.string('authors')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down() {
    this.drop('books')
  }
}
```

Models :

```js
class BookUnit extends Model {
    static get table() {
        return 'book_unit'
    }

    book() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Book')
    }
}

//==============================

class Book extends Model {
    book_units() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnit')
    }
}
```

Test :

```js
var data = {
        "book_id": 1,
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "status": false
    }
    const bookUnit = await BookUnit.create(data)
```

Result:
[image]

Test config :

- SQLite

Don't hesitate if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this

```
table.integer('book_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
```

next thing in your api its better to fetch the book by its id and then use create method.

```
let book = await Book.findBy('id',params.id)//your book id from your req object
book.book_units().create({
    "book_id": 1,
    "unit": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false
})
```